# Proving the existence of right derivative

Tags: derivatives

Suppose we have a continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$. We know that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b]$ and that there is a finite limit:

$$\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f^{\prime}(x)$$

Can we prove that $f$ has a right derivative in point $a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $x>a$ there exists $\xi \in (a,x)$ such that $$f(x)-f(a)=f'(\xi)(x-a).$$ If $x \to a$, then $\xi \to a$, and ...

Comment: Hm... Well, we can write the mean value theorem as:
$$f^{\prime}(\xi)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
So, as you said, if $x\to{a}^{+}$, then $\xi\to{a}^{+}$ as well. Therefore, we can take limits from both sides:

Comment: ...and we have:
$$\lim_{\xi\to{a}^{+}}f^{\prime}(\xi)=\lim_{x\to{a}^{+}}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

we know that the limit on the left side exists, and the limit on the right side is the right derivative in $a$... is that correct?

Comment: Yes. If you want to use kill a fly with a cannon, you can also use De l'Hospital. But it is too much, in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure if de l'Hospital would work, because $f^{\prime}(a)$ does not exist... We have only one-sided derivative in $a$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f'_+(a)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$$
By continuity of $f$, we have here indefinite symbol $\frac{[0]}{[0]}$. Using de L'Hospital rule we obtain

$$f'_+(a)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f'(x).$$
(The last limit exists by assumption).

Comment: Oh yes, now I understand what Siminore meant (I got confused by the fact that $f^{\prime}(a)$ doesn't exist, but since $f(a)$ is a constant it doesn't bother us in this case). Thanks.