Questions about exercise regarding right-hand limit of the derivative and right-hand derivative.
I am currently working on the following problem regarding the Mean Value Theorem:

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, and suppose that we have
$$\lim_{x\to a+}{f^\prime(x)}=C$$
for some fixed $C$. What can we conclude about the right derivative of $f$ at $a$?

My attempt is as follows. For all $x\in(a,b]$, we have continuity on $[a,x]$ and differentiability on $(a,x)$, so the Mean Value Theorem implies the existence of a $c_x\in(a,x)$ such that $f^\prime(c_x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. Therefore, we have
$$f_+^\prime(a)=\lim_{x\to a+}{\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}}=\lim_{x\to a+}{f^\prime(c_x)}$$
Next, we observe that $\lim_{x\to a+}{c_x}=a$, meaning $x\to a+$ implies $c_x \to a+$. Therefore,
$$\lim_{x\to a+}{f^\prime(c_x)}=\lim_{c_x\to a+}{f^\prime(c_x)}=C$$
whence we get
$$f_+^\prime(a)=C=\lim_{x\to a+}{f^\prime(x)}.$$
My questions are:

Is my reasoning correct?

The Mean Value Theorem implies the existence of $c_x$ for each $x$, but there could be multiple such $c_x$. Have I implicitly assumed the Axiom of Choice? Is there a way to do this proof without the Axiom of Choice?

The part where I change the conditions of the limits from $x \to a+$ to $c_x \to a+$ seems a little hand-wavy. How would one go about making this part more rigorous? (Is it even valid?)



Your reasoning is correct, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257907/42969. Also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1696717/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2129367/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/194086/42969.
